# System.out.print() is not worked, log4j still works well

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

may anyone explain for my question as below.

1. My java web application uses the org.apache.log4j.Logger library.
2. I put a command like: log.info("this is log4j output")
3. I put another command like System.out.println("This is system out put")
4. Ok, I deploy the web application by tomcat server.

Now, Im tracing log in catalina.out. **My question:**

During running of the application　"this is log4j output" is shown, but "This is system out put" is not shown.

This is log4j configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
          value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I think that both of them will be shown (log4j output and system.out).

I dont know why. May anyone explain the question?

Thanks!

Comment: System.out.print goes to the terminal of your server. check that (if there is one), it's one of the reasons you should never use System.out.print on a remote deployed piece of code

Comment: @Stultuske: yep, i have not use System.out.println in the latest code version. This is simply my question I want to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`System.out` prints to the "standard out" console. That can be your  text console, but it could be anything, as it can easily be  configured to go elsewhere.

On the other hand, any logger library can be configured to log to any place you want to.

Long story short: most likely, this is due to *some* specific  configuration setting in your environment. But we don't know your setup, so we can't give any more specific answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. I updated my question with log4j configuration. Are there any thing news in your answer?

Comment: You are welcome. I am not an expert down to that level, but I will  see what I can do.